# Azure Dev Ops Build Pipeline xunit nest fails (.net Core)

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, azure-devops, xunit

I have a xunit test project written in .net core 2.2 which is being built using Azure Dev Ops

I have a .NET Core stage that builds the test project first using a command of build, task version 2.*, this stage works but im not sure if its necessary.

I have tried a second .NET Core state task version 2.* with command of test, this was continuing forever so I set a short timeout of 1 min (for now)

Here I get errors such as Assert.Equal() Failure, Expected: OK, Actual:   0

I have also added a 3rd stage Visual Studio Test, task version 2.* test assemblies, I have tried using Specific Location and Version.

I have been toggling between trying the two test types and some googling hasn't resolved it.

The software is to build a .net core website and we have 3 sets of unit tests to mock some interfaces to APIs and a small helper library.

UPDATE

---

I have created a new Unit Testing Project using MSTest, in order to rule out xunit (for now)

The Yaml is below

steps:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\*test*.dll
     !**\*TestAdapter.dll
     !**\obj\**
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*\*unittests.dll
     !**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*
    vstestLocationMethod: location
    vstestLocation: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    otherConsoleOptions: '/Framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2 /logger:console;verbosity="normal"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
  timeoutInMinutes: 1
```

And here is an output from the log

```
========================================================
Test selector : Test assemblies
Test assemblies : **\*test*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**,**\Release\*\*unittests.dll,!**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*
Test filter criteria : null
Search folder : d:\a\1\s
Run settings file : d:\a\1\s
Run in parallel : false
Run in isolation : false
Path to custom adapters : null
Other console options : /Framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2 /logger:console;verbosity="normal"
Code coverage enabled : true
Diagnostics enabled : false
Rerun failed tests: false
vstest.console.exe, specified location : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\
========================================================
[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\*test*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**,**\Release\*\*unittests.dll,!**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*.
======================================================
```

Comment: Without any context about what the tested software and the tests do, there's nothing we can do. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added a sentence, Its difficult to know what code to paste in, i could paste in a sample test routine but that works when run in Visual Studio.  Perhaps i could add some more details about the test configuration if that helps.

Comment: I have created a new test project using Visual Studio Tests in order to rule out XUnit for now.